# how to force print dataframe in html in ipython

Tags: python, printing, ipython

Here's my code

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(6).reshape(3,2),
   ....:                 columns=['A','B'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(6).reshape(3,2),
   ....:                 columns=['C','D'])
print df1
print '--Something Here---'
df2
```

here, I would get both df1 and df2 to print but only df2 that created HTML look.
How can I force python to create df1 to print to html in output as well as df2 
[image]

Comment: You can find this in [the examples of the doc](http://nbviewer.ipython.org/github/ipython/ipython/blob/1.x/examples/notebooks/Part%205%20-%20Rich%20Display%20System.ipynb) Focus on understanding the difference between the **output** of a cell and a **display**-ed object. (Hint it's like print vs return for a function)

Comment: In short: `from IPython.display import display`, then `display(df1)`.

Comment: Oooh, very useful for print loops! :D

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure I totally understand the point of this. Why for example would you jsut not display the output in two different cells. In general in order to force the HMTL display of data in the notebook (if for example the dataframe is too large) then you do the following

```
from IPython.core.display import HTML
HMTL(df.to_html())
```

Does this answer you quetion?

In cell 1 I would have

```
HMTL(df.to_html())
```

In cell 2 I would have

```
print 'something'
HTML(df2.to_html())
```